# How to rotate non square two dimensional array twice to have all possible rotations?

Tags: javascript, arrays, rotation

You can find a lot of answers to "rotate square two dimensional array", but not "rotate non square two dimensional array", and even though some answers do work like this one:

```
    rotate(tab) {                                                            
        return tab[0].map(function(col, i) {                                 
            return tab.map(function(lig) {                                   
                return lig[i];                                               
            })                                                               
        });                                                                  
    }
```

They only work the first time you rotate. If you rotate again, you go back to the first array, which is not what I want, I want all 3 possible combinations of an array rotated by 90'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the length of the array for calculating the new positions.

> ```
> original   left    right
> -------- -------- --------
> 1  2  3   4  1     3  6
> 4  5  6   5  2     2  5
>           6  3     1  4
> ```

```js
function rotateRight(array) {
    var result = [];
    array.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
        a.forEach(function (b, j, bb) {
            result[bb.length - j - 1] = result[bb.length - j - 1] || [];
            result[bb.length - j - 1][i] = b;
        });
    });
    return result;
}

function rotateLeft(array) {
    var result = [];
    array.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
        a.forEach(function (b, j, bb) {
            result[j] = result[j] || [];
            result[j][aa.length - i - 1] = b;
        });
    });
    return result;
}

var array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]];

console.log(rotateLeft(array));
console.log(rotateRight(array));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Just a quick question: your code works flawlessly... why not call rotateLeft() twice?

Comment: @OlivierPons, you can do that, for right, you neet to call left three times, but i like to have both direction to choose.

Comment: When using forEach on a 2D array I would expect the first to parameters to be the element, and the index, but what are `aa` and `bb` ? And why are they what they are?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [gridl](https://gridl.dev), a small library I've written to deal with all kinds of 2d grid operations. It supports [rotations](https://gridl.dev/api-docs/#rotate90) as well.

```js
const {createGridFromArray2D, rotate90} = gridl;

const array2D = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
];
const grid = createGridFromArray2D(array2D);
const rotationSteps = 1;
const rotatedGrid = rotate90(rotationSteps)(grid);

console.log(rotatedGrid.array2D);
// [
//     [4, 1],
//     [5, 2],
//     [6, 3],
// ]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gridl@0.11.9/_umd/index.min.js"></script>
```

You could also rotate the grid in other directions quite easily:

```js
rotate(1);  // rotates 1 time clockwise (90 degrees)
rotate(2);  // rotates 2 times clockwise (180 degrees)
rotate(3);  // rotates 3 times clockwise (270 degrees)
rotate(-1); // rotates 1 time counterclockwise (-90 degrees)
rotate(-2); // rotates 2 times counterclockwise (-180 degrees)
rotate(-3); // rotates 3 times counterclockwise (-270 degrees)
```