# Assigning to array doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to rotate array clockwise for example
from:

```
[[1,2,3], 
 [4,5,6], 
 [7,8,9]]
```

make:

```
   [[7,4,1], 
    [8,5,2], 
    [9,6,3]]
```

so I written a function for that its looks as below:

```
function rotateImage(a) {
    const arr = Array(a.length).fill(Array(a.length).fill(0));
    for(let i =0; i< a.length; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < a[i].length;j++ ){
            console.log(i,j);
            arr[j][a[i].length-1 - i] = a[i][j];
            console.log(arr)
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

here are logs i get:

```
0 0
[ [ 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 1 ] ]  
0 1
[ [ 0, 0, 2 ], [ 0, 0, 2 ], [ 0, 0, 2 ] ] 
0 2
[ [ 0, 0, 3 ], [ 0, 0, 3 ], [ 0, 0, 3 ] ]
1 0
[ [ 0, 4, 3 ], [ 0, 4, 3 ], [ 0, 4, 3 ] ]
1 1
[ [ 0, 5, 3 ], [ 0, 5, 3 ], [ 0, 5, 3 ] ] 
1 2
[ [ 0, 6, 3 ], [ 0, 6, 3 ], [ 0, 6, 3 ] ]
2 0
[ [ 7, 6, 3 ], [ 7, 6, 3 ], [ 7, 6, 3 ] ]
2 1
[ [ 8, 6, 3 ], [ 8, 6, 3 ], [ 8, 6, 3 ] ]
2 2
[ [ 9, 6, 3 ], [ 9, 6, 3 ], [ 9, 6, 3 ] ]
```

so when i have `i=0` and `j=0`, My code should turn to something like this:

```
arr[0][2]= a[0][0];
// so I should get 
[ [ 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ] ]
// insted of 
[ [ 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 1 ] ]
```

can somebody explain for me what is going on here?

Comment: you may have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42581128/1447675

Comment: Part of your problem lies in the way you are using fill. That may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949813/array-fillarray-creates-copies-by-references-not-by-value

Comment: Your outer array contains three references to the same array, so when you change a cell in one of the lines you're changing it in all of them.

Comment: From your problem statement it doesn't look like you've got any reason to initialize your array with zeroes anyway, so just use `arr = [[],[],[]]` and you should be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is the output array

Solution :

```
function rotateImage(a) {
    let arr = Array(a.length);

    for(let i =0; i< 3; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < a[i].length;j++ ){
                if(!arr[j]) {
                    arr[j] = Array(a[j].length)
                }
                arr[j][a[i].length-1 - i] =  a[i][j];
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the way you created your output array:

```
const arr = Array(a.length).fill(Array(a.length).fill(0));
```

This says "Every element of `arr` should equal the result of `Array(a.length).fill(0)`. That is to say, array `arr` has three elements, each of which is *the same object*.

Therefore, when you assign a value to `arr[0][2]`, you are also assigning it to `arr[1][2]`, etc.

You could use a loop like this to create your new matrix:

```
var arr = Array(a[0].length);
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    arr[i] = Array(a.length).fill(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

This function can be written as three maps, in a one-liner:

```js
const rotateImage = a =>  a[0].map((_, i) => a.map(r => r[i])).map(r => r.reverse())

console.log(rotateImage([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
]))
```

Note that this works with non-square grids as well.